# How should I create a new Federated Identity Provider for Firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, node.js, paypal, firebase-authentication

I would like to integrate PayPal signin into an android app so to authenticate the client to the Firebase Database. I've managed to create a custom funtion on the node.js server that creates tokens from the provided uid, in order to use "signin withcustomtoken" function in the client application. Should I send the uid to the nodejs server through https in order to get the token? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create an HTTP endpoint that accepts a `uid` and returns a custom token. This is a huge security vulnerability as any attacker would be able to impersonate any user knowing their `uid`.
What you need to do is the following:

1. Implement a paypal OAuth code flow. You can use third party libraries for that.
2. When you get the paypal OAuth authorization code, you send it to your backend, you use the paypal client ID and secret to exchange for a paypal refresh token and access token. You can then get the user info associated with that paypal user including their paypal uid. You would then mint a Firebase custom token using the Firebase Admin SDKs and return it to the client.
3. On the client you would `signInWithCustomToken` to complete sign in with that custom token.

In this case you are exposing an HTTP endpoint that takes an authorization code and returns a Firebase custom token.

This is the basic idea (details excluded). Of course you still have to ensure the flow starts and ends on the same device by passing some state and then check that you get it back in the end. You also have to ensure the auth code is returned to the correct app using something like app links, etc. Firebase Dynamic Links can be helpful there.

Comment: Infact that was my concern about security. Since firebase doesn't allow me to communicate with external servers directly, I've decided to use google authentication in the first place. then I would add a flag in the database to mark if the user has or not a verified PayPal account, and update it implementing Paypal oauth entirely in the client app. I think  I could use the nodejs function to return the base64 clientid:secret to work with the pp aouth flow on the client. Do you think is a good idea? Thanks

Comment: No of course not. Do not return client ID or secret to the client. The auth code flow is meant to complete on a backend server.

Comment: Ok I think I'll try to obfuscate the api secret inside the app and see how it goes. There is no point for me to switch to a paid plan or to set up my own server at this stage

Comment: Obfuscation does nothing especially when you are passing a hard coded string. You are putting all your users at risk here. If there is one rule in security, you are violating it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I think I'm only putting at risk my own api key from paypal. Other than that evreything runs over https

Comment: From my understanding, you plan to do the OAuth exchange on the client side instead of doing so on the backend which involves storing the client ID and secret in the app. This will mean an attacker will be able to get hold of those and easily phish your users.

Comment: How much easily? The "Log In with paypal" interface doesn't show the app name requesting the access to the user, so I imagine that it is contextual. The phisher could use its own secret and id to obtain the same result

Comment: The attacker can simply inspect the network requests in the console. They would try to sign in with paypal and monitor the network requests to paypal endpoints and in the process get your client id and secret if you are doing the exchange on the client.

Comment: I got it. I'll have to try to use a server with php and stuff..even if i've read in other answers obout people using the api in the client. I couldn't get a clear answer about everything here. I dont understand why google decided to forbid outbound networking in the firebase basic plan. Afterall they make so much more money everytime a developer decide to use their infrastructure...this system is filthy...I'm gonna give you the best answer mark even if you really didnt answer to my question, you just told me what is already available on the web