# OAuth2 access token exchange failing when called from Firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, discord

I'm having trouble getting an access token for the Discord API using OAuth2 authorization code grant.  I was able to get the token successfully by sending the following request from my web app:

```
const params = `client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&response_type=code&scope=identify`;

fetch(`${apiUrl}/oauth2/token`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: params,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
}).then(json => {
    console.log(json);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${e}`);
});
```

In order to register my user with my Firebase app I am sort of following the steps outlined in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415787/how-should-i-create-a-new-federated-identity-provider-for-firebase-authenticatio) to request the access token through a cloud function and the next step would be to create a custom token and then use `signInWithCustomToken` to authenticate the user with my app.

However, when I run the exact same snippet of code in my cloud function, the response I get from Discord's OAuth2 server is this:

```
{
    error: 'invalid_request',
    error_description: 'Invalid "code" in request.'
}
```

I am not sure what that means.  Unless I'm missing something, the `code` parameter I'm passing in both requests is the same, which I have confirmed by logging and comparing both.  I think it might be related to where the function is being run (some Google server somewhere), but I thought it would be fine since my `client_id` and `client_secret` are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

It turns out I was sending the access token exchange request twice (once from the client, once from the cloud function), which resulted in the slightly slower cloud function to always sending the request last, and since the second request reused the authorization code from the first request, it was deemed invalid.